# JSP Declaration can't find crypto algorithms

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I'm working with a canned product where my only way to customize it involves working solely with JSPs (not Servlets or anything else). I'm trying to split out a commonly-used piece of code into a method specified in a JSP declaration.

```
<%!
private void myMethod() {
  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
}
%>
```

This throws a `NoSuchAlgorithmException` exception on JSP compilation, whereas something like the following in a *scriptlet* compiles fine.

```
<%
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
%>
```

Any idea why it's barfing on this in a JSP declaration, yet works fine from within a scriptlet?

Comment: How are you calling `myMethod()`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The exception is thrown on JSP compilation, before any code is executed. It fails compilation whether the method is called in a scriptlet, expression, or not at all.